# Is it OK if I used word "f---" in my topic for my teacher?

Tags: word-choice, offensive-language

My school teacher asked my to make a topic about something that I do well, so I decided to write about my knowledge in electronics engineering.
So I want to write a sentence like "what the *fuck* is electronics engineering"

Is it OK if I used that word? (Lots of people think that electronics is not something worthy, and they say why do I need it).
any better word to describe this situation?

Comment: *What the hell is electronics engineering?*

Comment: @NathanTuggy You should change "my" to "me" in the first sentence. You should change the order in "why do I need it". You should capitalize "any" in the last sentence. Please.

Comment: @Rathony: I said I fixed *some* typos; I deliberately left some more characteristic of the asker's English level.

Comment: @Rathony: See e.g. [StoneyB's take on the utility of leaving questions less than flawlessly corrected](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/1061/10820).

Comment: No it is not okay. Use *heck*.

Comment: @Rathony - After you have read the wisdom of StoneyB, please refrain from leaving comments about an answer should or should not be edited. These comments are distracting and unproductive.

Comment: @J.R. I have just read StoneyB's answer and I agree with him 100%. To be honest, I don't understand what you are trying to say here. Changing "my" to "me", "any" to "Any" doesn't change anything about OP's English-language sophistication or intention of the question. They are just typos that we always edit in this community. Are you against editing typos? StoneyB doesn't seem to be against changing typos. I have never lefts comments about an ***answer*** should or should not be edited. What are you talking about?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I totally agree with your editing the f-word. But, why did you capitalize ***Lots*** and leaving ***any*** without capitalizing it. Why did you change ***ok*** to ***OK***? Aren't they showing some characteristic of the OP's level? Why did you even edit others (excluding the f-word) in the first place then? Is there a rule here that we have to edit half of the typos to show the OP's English level properly?

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not Ok.  Using a curse word is unprofessional and shows your writing skills are not creative.  It shows you can't think of any other way to convey what you want to say, except by cursing.

You can say something like, "So, What is Electrical Engineering, anyway?"  Or " So, What's the Big Deal about Electrical Engineering?" Or even "Do We Really Need Electrical Engineers?"

Comment: Or just replace the vulgar word, for example, "What the heck is Electrical Engineering? "

Comment: @ColleenV - While I agree that _heck_ is much preferable over the original, I find Kitty's suggestions here even better.